BibLaTeX changes the title of list of abbreviations
I am working on my PhD thesis and I use biblatex-apa for citations and references and leipzig for glossaries of abbreviations. However, when I print the glossaries, biblatex seems to automatically change the title of the list of abbreviations to "Glossary", which should be "Abbreviations" by default.
I have tried to redefine \leipzigname to "Abbreviations", but it doesn't work. Is there a way to change the title back to "Abbreviations" or prevent it from being changed to "Glossary"?
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, british]{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[mcolblock]{leipzig}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\printglossaries
\Nom{}

\end{document}


Welcome to tex.sx.

The babel package will translate the glossary title into whatever language you specified. In your case, you change the British "translation" like this:
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, british]{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[mcolblock]{leipzig}
\makeglossaries

\addto\captionsbritish{%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{Abbreviations}%
}

\begin{document}

\printglossaries
\Nom{}

\end{document}


It works like a charm! Thank you for saving my day! Though I still don't know why this problem occurs with biblatex in the first place.

@JiaHulio biblatex isn't related. You can reproduce the problem by just loading babel.

I see. I have tried and exactly, the problem is with babel.
